# AWS Serverless Application Publish via Visual Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

Using .Net Core, visual studio 2017 and AWS Toolkit for Visual 2017, I created a basic web api, the api works as designed.

However when it comes to publishing/deploying it, the first time works perfectly when the Stack doesnt exist, creates everything its suppose to. When I make a change and need to re-deployed/publish, it comes back with the following error.

> Error creating CloudFormation change set: Stack [TestStack] already exists and cannot be created again with the changeSet [Lambda-Tools-636366731897711782].

Just above the error message is this

> Found existing stack: False

Im wondering if there is something not quite right with it detecting if the Stack exists.

**Im just wondering if Im missing something, or if this is actually be design, as for me to republish it I have to log into my AWS Console and go into the cloud formation section and delete the existing Stack.**

Publish Dialog

[image: Publish Dialog]

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, and general trial and error. I believe this is actually to do with permissions of the user performing the publish. (The user in AWS)

I changed an inline policy to

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `cloudformation:*` used to be several lines for individual permissions.

This now successfully publishes over an existing Stack, however visual studio doesnt like it and crashes. (Although the update does go through to AWS)

Comment: I'm having the same issue (or a similar one?) where it crashes after publishing, and I've found that it's not the publish that actually kills VS, it's the AWS Toolkit's CloudFormation stack viewer. To confirm this, I open VS2017, to the AWS Explorer, go to the AWS CloudFormation node, expand it, and double-click (or right-click -> open) the stack. VS immediately crashes. VS2017 activityLog shows "element with same key already exists" error for AWSToolkitPackage.dll.
It's quite annoying.

Comment: There has to be a more concise set of `cloudformation:` policy permissions that `sam deploy` needs. I'm hitting this same issue, with attempting to author an IAM Policy for app (re-)deploy granting only the permissions required.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS' Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) is … very new still. And for lack of any documentation about what IAM permission one needs to deploy an App with their CLI, I've worked out this policy that seems to work, and only [grants the least needed permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) for the task.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
                "cloudformation:ListChangeSets",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:123456789012:function:*-SAM-*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:123456789012:stack/<STACK NAME OR GLOB>/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:<AWS_REGION>:aws:transform/Serverless-2016-10-31",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Note:

Replace `<STACK NAME OR GLOB>` with something that best suits your needs, like:

- `*` If you don't care which CloudFormation Stack this grants access to
- `*-SAM-*` If you name your SAM CloudFormation apps with some consistency

Replace `<AWS_REGION>` with the region you're operating in.

The `arn:aws:s3:::aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-*` is the standard bucket naming that SAM CLI uses for creating a bucket for deploying CloudFormation Templates or Change Sets. You could alter this to explicitly be the name of the bucket SAM created for you.

Comment: There likely are even more permissions to add to this, depending on whether a deployed app will be interfacing with other AWS Services. But this is what worked for us, in redeploying our one SAM App that needs to talk to DynDB.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the CodeBuild pipeline and was facing the same issue.

As, CodeBuild pipeline uses IAM role, I ended up adding below permssions to IAM Role.

```
{
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
            "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
            "lambda:ListTags",
            "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "cloudformation:ListChangeSets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

If you are deploying using Visual Studio, you must have added IAM User Profile in your VS.

Please make sure your IAM user have above permsssions.

[image]